# Object instantiation error because of namespace

Tags: c++, qt, namespaces

So, I have this class inside a namespace but when i try to create an instance i get the following error message:

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H
#include "constants.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <QVector>

namespace Compressor {
class File;
}

class File {
public:
    QVector<QVector<int>> bytes;
    int length;
public:
    File(int l);
};

#endif // FILE_H
```

...

```
#include "file.h"

File::File(int l) {
    length = l;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        QVector<int> b;

        for(int j = 0; j < BYTESIZE; j++)
            b.push_back(rand( ) % 2);

        bytes.push_back( b );
    }
}
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
```

...

```
#include "file.h"
#include "tableconfig.h"
#include "tableshow.h"

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Compressor::File *fl;
//...
//...
```

...

```
void MainWindow::on_buttonOrigin_clicked( ) {
    fl = new Compressor::File( ui->spinBox->value( ) ); // The problem happens here.
    showBytesTable(ui->tableOrigin, fl);
}
```

Here the error message:

> /home/roger/Programming/C-C++/Linux/Qt/Compressor-4bits/mainwindow.cpp:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Compressor::File’
>   fl = new Compressor::File( ui->spinBox->value( ) );
>   ^

How can I fix that?

Comment: `Compressor::File` is in no way related to `File`. And since `Compressor::File` is not defined (it is only declared), it is of an incomplete type. What, exactly, is unclear?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Well, it might be not so evident for someone with less experience. Maybe your comment could be the answer for this question.

Comment: @Oscar In that case, I would advise that someone to read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), since topic of namespaces should be covered in those.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing as "mainwindow.h" created automatically when i use qtcreator. In this class definition i have "namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {//..."

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the namespace right behind the first line:

```
namespace Compressor {
class File;
}
```

and then your complete class `File` is defined outside of the namespace. This is another `File` for the compiler than the one you start inside the namespace (which contains nothing, just a forward declaration)